# Is it possible to write a GA without giving it a target value?

Tags: genetic-algorithms

For example, if i write "helo wrld" in a text box could i write an algorithm that would change it to "hello world" or find all the closest solutions to what i write? without actually telling the algorithm that "hello world" is what i'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, but you have to build your goals into the algorithm very explicitly, e.g. by writing an objective function to be optimized. For example, perhaps you want the most probable sequence of valid English words (which you would have to make mathematically precise to write an objective function).